# rewrite rule fails on IE but working on other browsers

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer

In our site i had a set of rules to add www in our domain and to remove index.
These rules are:

```
#######################################################
# remove index.htm/html from url
# rewrite non-www into www
#
#  RULE A = combine both lack of www and presence of index
#  RULE B = only lackof www
#  RULE C = presence of index (htm or html)
######################################################
#rule A
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)(index\.html|index\.htm)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#rule B
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#rule C
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)(index\.html|index\.htm)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This was working as intended up to 3 days ago.
Now this rule fails in IE8-IE11 but keeps working in other browsers in my PC (FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari).

Note1: when i say it fails, I mean only the **www adding part**. Removing index still works in all browsers. (in other words, example.com is NOT redirected to www.example.com)

Note 2: all tests in all browsers are with clear cache/browser/website data.

Any ideas on what to look/fix/update?

Comment: just a guess, search for `downgrade-1.0` in the apache configuration file and comment it if found?

Comment: @regilero ty - i will search for it